# Forwarding A Request From One Controller Function To Another in Spring 2.5.2

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two classes called : 
List of users page
Edit user page

Iam using `SimpleFormController` in **spring** 2.5.2 version. 
In this bellow method I want to edit the users information. After successfully submitting this form I need to forward the page to list of users page.

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response, Object command, BindException errors){
}
```

I configured this edit page in `dispatcher-servlet` as bellow:

```
<bean name="edituser" class="com.users.EditUserController"/>
```

How can I forward the page from `onsubmit` method.

Comment: Iam using xml based configuration.

Comment: I configured this edit page in dispatcher-servlet as bellow:
<bean name="edituser" class="com.users.EditUserController"/>

Comment: iam using return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("http://localhost:8080/edituser.htm"); but it is not working.

Comment: Could you post the full code for the Edit Controller, the List Controller and the corresponding JSPs?

Comment: public class EditUser extends SimpleFormController{
public EditCorporateContractController(){
setCommandClass(AddUserBean.class);
setCommandName("editUser");
setFormView("/users/EditUser");
setSuccessView("/users/EditUser");
}
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
//request handling and code
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
map.put("process_status", "success");
}else{
map.put("process_status", "Error");
}
}
return  new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users/listofusers"));
}
}

Comment: When you say it's not working, what are you getting? Are you seeing an error? If so, can you post that?

Comment: no iam not getting any error. but request not forward to listofusers.htm. empty page is appear.

Comment: my intention is to forward the page to listofusers.htm when the edit is completed..

Comment: Can you hit /users/listofusers directly in a browser and does this return a page? Since you're redirecting between edit and listofusers, try using Firebug (or similar) to see the requests the browser makes after completing the edit.